# Prevent sorting in datagrid from resetting rows visibility property

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, visibility

Is there a way to prevent DataGrid sorting to reset rows visibility?

I tried re-setting visibility in "Sorting" event with no luck.
Rows appear to have correct visibility but when GUI draws all rows are visible.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ErrorsList" Style="{StaticResource MyDataGrid}" Visibility="Hidden" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Sorting="ErrorsList_OnSort">
```

CS:

```
private void ErrorsList_OnSort(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
      // no effect whatsoever
      ChangeErrorsListRowsVisibility();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... this worked for me.

```
private void ErrorsList_OnSort(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
   ErrorsList.LoadingRow += ErrorsList_LoadingRow;
}
```

and...

```
void ErrorsList_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
   // Here I handled the visibility for each row
}
```